# Postfix: How to check if my email headers are RFC5321/RFC5322 compliant?

Tags: email, postfix, email-bounces

We are running a Postfix MTA (version: 3.4.14, OS: Debian 10) and since a short time emails sent to a certain provider (Web.de/GMX) are not being accepted anymore (the emails are sent by an ancient Perl program, which has always worked reliably so far):

```
Jan 26 10:21:51 hostname postfix/smtp[24531]: 5915310CD43: to=<recipient@web.de>, relay=mx-ha02.web.de[212.227.17.8]:25, delay=0.34, delays=0. 01/0/0.18/0.15, dsn=5.0.0, status=bounced (host mx-ha02.web.de[212.227.17.8] said: 554-Transaction failed 554-Reject due to policy restrictions. 554 For explanation visit https://web.de/email/senderguidelines?ip=1.3.5.2&c=hi (in reply to end of DATA command))
```

I sent an email to the operator of Web.de and got the following answer:

> E-mails will be rejected by our mail system if the information given in the e-mail header does not comply with the specifications in RFC 5321 and RFC 5322. This includes the following points:
>
> - The following headers must be syntactically correct: Date, From, Sender, To
> - The headers BCC, CC, Date, From, Sender, Subject and To must not appear more than once.
>
> Therefore, please check the information provided by your system for correctness and contact the administrator of your system if necessary. Please also note our sender guidelines:
>
> https://www.gmx.net/mail/senderguidelines/
>
> https://web.de/email/senderguidelines/

I checked the headers and they don't appear more than once (this is an email I sent to my private email address):

```
Return-Path: <www-data@sender.com>
Delivered-To: myaddress@mydomain.com
Received: from mail.mypersonalmta.com
        by mail.mypersonalmta.com with LMTP
        id Mj4HKoIHEGATFAAA8lfkpQ
        (envelope-from <www-data@sender.com>)
        for <myaddress@mydomain.com>; Tue, 26 Jan 2021 13:13:54 +0100
Received: from sender.com (sender.com [1.1.1.1])
        by mail.mypersonalmta.com (Postfix) with ESMTPS id 311DC3EBDA
        for <myaddress@mydomain.com>; Tue, 26 Jan 2021 13:13:54 +0100 (CET)
Received: by sender.com (Postfix, from userid 33)
        id DFAF110CBE9; Tue, 26 Jan 2021 13:13:51 +0100 (CET)
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Reply-to: "My Name" <myaddress@work.com>
From: "My Name" <myaddress@work.com>
To: "My Name" <myaddress@mydomain.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?B?U2VydmVya29uZmlndXJhdGlvbg==?=
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-type: multipart/mixed;
        boundary="==Serviceplaner==multipart/mixed==0=="
Message-Id: <20210126121351.DFAF110CBE9@sender.com>
Date: Tue, 26 Jan 2021 13:13:51 +0100 (CET)
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=mydomain.com;
        s=dk100; t=1611663234;
        h=from:from:reply-to:reply-to:subject:subject:date:date:
         message-id:message-id:to:to:cc:mime-version:mime-version:
         content-type:content-type; bh=b1FPU+OUKvDQDm+TJNNJ4gnjC2tvP3esicGNZxlMRGU=;
        b=NGDHmG4XaGZYCkDB4iT7MlzYTREHbpL5QrJZm1guR2CsL18B6efRf7SU+roM+p9vaY/8VI
        5g77bu9XiQ1Uz9g2wqHfKQ45Kh7pPjlxxT9gugKBi+Wb0eo0oQQ/C+dLe/LdRRZqnY+4Gc
        lnmpO6FXv9i7sfNXkcHUq62UPQIBT40=
ARC-Seal: i=1; s=dk100; d=mydomain.com; t=1611663234; a=rsa-sha256;
        cv=none;
        b=xMVJHET/VP+NQdzb2osJo1BVLMgCX60/0SL9ZSywsJiDEkUReK8wedi2Ahw+kSBypj+XWO
        TKH7/OZjWxbzUlKeMqFo4kLpHj2ygIu2ThXpYXYbW/D+tNG7CK7f3byz+j8myaddressGj+g9hQ05
        I0LnjAInYPniK8qGsFJG4sXvrUb/7CY=
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1;
        mail.mypersonalmta.com;
        dkim=none;
        spf=pass (mail.mypersonalmta.com: domain of www-data@sender.com designates 1.1.1.1 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=www-data@sender.com
X-Spamd-Bar: ++++
X-Spam-Level: ****
Authentication-Results: mail.mypersonalmta.com;
        dkim=none;
        dmarc=none;
        spf=pass (mail.mypersonalmta.com: domain of www-data@sender.com designates 1.1.1.1 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=www-data@sender.com
```

I don’t know how to check if the email headers are syntactically correct and RFC5321/RFC5322 compliant. I have an idea, but I'm not quite sure: Maybe it's because there's UTF8 in the Subject header (UTF-8 that's converted to ASCII is maybe a problem, I don't know)? How would you proceed in this case? Any ideas? :)

Comment: One thing I can say for sure: GMX does *not* care about badly formatted mail that much. Sure, if that is what the tell you to do, eliminate all problems in that area, but do not expect identifying and fixing a syntax problem to be the only step necessary for them to accept your mail again.

Answer (score 3):

The boilerplate referring to fixing your mail syntax is not likely indicating a problem with that specifically - it is just one of the things you *can* do while there may not be much you can do about e.g. them (or their information sources, namely Spamhaus) not liking your hosting provider.

One common problem is headers appearing different to the recipient than to you, because of inconsistent folding.

You could be inadvertently ending your headers early and thus missing mandatory headers - or ending one body part without CRLF so the recipient is unable to use the multipart boundary assuming an incomplete mail.

Have some other program parse your mail - your raw mail, not a copy-pasted version where your editor has already neatly canonicalized all **line endings** with single `\n`.

```
cat ~/MAIL/Sent/cur/ui.uid.a,S | python3 -c 'import sys,email,email.policy; print("\n".join(part.get_content_type() for part in email.message_from_file(sys.stdin, policy=email.policy.SMTP+email.policy.strict).walk()))'
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment and reply! +1 Could you please tell me where to find/how to catch the raw emails (since there's no Dovecot running on the system where emails are being saved)? The Python code is nice, but without a raw email I won't be able to use it :)

Comment: As long as there is one local mailbox (e.g. some mail going to `/var/spool/mail/root`) temporarily adding that as another unlisted recipient (BCC) should be enough to have an almost-verbatim copy of the mail show up there.